# Display count of column excluding min and max values

Tags: mysql, sql, count, greatest-n-per-group, having-clause

I want to count how many unique occurrences of an activity occurs in the table (FRIENDS) below. Then, I want to print the activities whom which their occurrences are *not* the maximum or minimum value of all occurrences.

```
***ID/Name/Activity***
1/James/Horse Riding
2/Eric/Eating
3/Sean/Eating
4/John/Horse Riding
5/Chris/Eating
6/Jessica/Paying
```

Ex:

```
Horse Riding occur 140 times
Playing occurs 170 times
Eating occurs 120 times
Walking occurs 150 times
Running occurs 200 times
```

The max occurrence here is Running, occurring 200 times, and the minimum occurrence here is Eating, occurring 120 times.

Therefore, I want to display

```
Horse Riding
Playing
Walking
```

In no particular order.

This is a code I have so far, but I keep getting a syntax error. When I don't get a syntax error, I get a "Every derived table must have its own alias error." I am new to SQL so I appreciate any advice I can get.

```
SELECT ACTIVITY, count(ACTIVITY) as Occurences FROM FRIENDS,
(SELECT MAX(Occur) AS Ma,MIN(Occur) AS Mi FROM (SELECT ACTIVITY, count(ACTIVITY) as Occur
FROM FRIENDS GROUP by City)) as T 
GROUP BY City HAVING Occurences!=T.Ma AND Occurences!=T.Mi ORDER BY Occurences DESC
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with aggregation and window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select activity, count(*) cnt,
        rank() over(order by count(*)) rn_asc,
        rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn_desc
    from mytable 
    group by activity
) t
where rn_asc > 1 and rn_desc > 1
```

The subquery counts the occurences of each activity, and ranks them in both ascending and descending oders. All that is left to do is exclude the top and bottom records. If there are top ties (or bottoms), the query evicts them.

In earlier versions, an option is a `having` clause:

```
select activity, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
group by activty
having count(*) > (select count(*) from mytable group by activity order by count(*) limit 1)
   and count(*) < (select count(*) from mytable group by activity order by count(*) desc limit 1)
```